# Trying to prove that if $f:[a, b]\to[s, t]$ is monotone then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I'm trying to prove that if $f:[a, b]\to[s, t]$ is monotone (and its image is closed interval) then $f$ is continuous.

My attempt:

I say wlog, $f$ is increasing. I know that a monotone function only has jump discontinuities, so let's say $c\in [a, b]$ is a jump discontinuity, so:

$$K=\lim\limits_{x\to c^-} f(x)<\lim\limits_{x\to c^+} f(x)=L$$

So for each $c<x_n\to c$, $f(x_n)\to L$. $x_n>c$ so $f(x_n)\ge f(c)$ so $f(c)\le L$.

And for each $c>y_n\to c$, $f(y_n)\to K$. $y_n<c$ so $f(y_n)\le f(c)$ so $f(c)\ge K$.

So $L=K$ and this is the contradiction.

And my question - where did I use that the image of $f$ is closed interval? Did I do something wrong?

thanks?

Comment: Your conclusion that $L=K$ is not supported by what you have done so far.

Comment: Oh I see.... Is this the right way though?

Comment: As you noticed, you need to incorporate the fact that the function's image is an interval. So there must be points in $[a,b]$ which map to points between $L$ and $K$, but how?

Comment: Using my attempt of solution you mean, or another way?

Comment: After you conclude that $K\leq f(c)\leq L$, show that the existence of $K<y<f(c)$ or $f(c)<y<L$ leads to a contradiction. Conclude that $K=f(c)=L$.

Comment: There are two problems with your approach. The first is trivial: $K \leq f(c) \leq L$ does not contradict $K < L$ ... YET. The second is: what if $c = a$? There are no $y_n < c = a$ that falls in the $f$'s domain. So saying $f(y_n) \leq f(c)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Could the range be an interval, if $K<L$? There is your contradiction.

Comment: Well, if you do not use the fact that $f$ maps the closed interval $[a,b]$ to the closed interval $[s,t]$, then the assertion is false. It is easy to construct  a counterexample, consisting of an increasing function with jump discontinuities.